# Firefox doesn't handle Ajax request like others

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I have this little bit of code on my (mvc) site to get a piece of info through Ajax. No problem so far, at least in all browsers, but one; Firefox doesn't recognize this and goes directly to the default controller instead of the Ajax controller.

`$('.navbar li a').click(function(e) {
event.preventDefault();`

I have been searching, but I really don't understand why Firefox is such a pain in the ass. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), "window.event is a proprietary Microsoft Internet Explorer property ...".

Change

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to

```
e.preventDefault();
```

`e` is a [jQuery Event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object), which normaizes disparate browser behaviours.